# Why are these "///////" in the rendered jinja2 template?

Tags: flask, jinja2

The route in question is straight forward-

```
@app.route('/user_access', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def user_access():
    userlist  = User.query.all()
    username = current_user.username
    return render_template("userlist.html", userlist=userlist, username=username)
```

template is simple as well...

```
    {% extends "base.html" %}
    {% block content %}
    <div class="container">
    <h2>Users with access to PCBevo </h2>

        <table class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>UserID</th>
                    <th>Email</th>
                <tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                {% for record in userlist %}
                <tr>
                    <td>{{record.username}}</td>
                    <td>{{record.email}}</td>/
                </tr>
                {% endfor %}
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <p><a href="/register_user">Add a new user to the access list</a></p>
    </div> <!-- /container -->
    {% endblock %}
```

But for some reason that I do not understand,  The template renders with a bunch of slashes.  Anyone know why this is?
[image]

Comment: `<td>{{record.email}}</td>/` trailing forward slash? Although, I would have expected this to show up in the table row.

Comment: @atwalsh Thank you for catching that!   Add it as a answer and I will give it the green check!

Answer (score 1):

There is a trailing forward slash after one of your table cells:

`<td>{{record.email}}</td>/`